# Having trouble flattening a nested object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I'm pretty new with d3 trying to make me a groped and stacked radial barplot, and I'm having trouble figuring out a structure for it. Before I attempted grouping my chart I was using a single nested object which I would then flatten down for the scales and such. However, since I'm now grouping it I'm realizing I might have to use two keys for my nested dataset, and now I'm having trouble flattening it.

So my dataset (after nesting it using the code below) is currently structured like this:

```
        [{key: "Grass", values: [
                {key: "Bulbasaur", values: [
                        Name: "Bulbasaur", Type: "Grass", HP: 45...},
                {key: "Ivysaur", values:
                        Name: "Ivysaur", Type: "Grass", HP: 60...}, ...]}
        [{key: "Fire", values: [
                {key: "Charmander", values: [
                        Name: "Charmander", Type: "Fire", HP: 45...},
                {key: "Charmeleon", values:
                        Name: "Charmeleon", Type: "Fire", HP: 60...}, ...]}
        [{key: "Water", values: ....}]
```

I'm looking to flatten it down so it looks something like this:

```
{Type: "Grass", Name: "Bulbasaur", HP: "45", Attack: "49", Defense: "49", ...}
{Type: "Grass", Name: "Ivysaur", HP: "60", Attack: "62", Defense: "63", ...}
{Type: "Fire", Name: "Charmander", HP: "39", Attack: "52", Defense: "43", ...}
{Type: "Fire", Name: "Charmeleon", HP: "58", Attack: "64", Defense: "58", ...}
```

This is the code I've used to make the nested object:

```
var newData = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d){return d["Type 1"]})
        .key(function(d){return d["Name"]})

        .rollup(function(v) {return {
            Type: v[0]["Type 1"],
            Name: v[0]["Name"],
            HP: v[0]["HP"],
            Attack: v[0]["Attack"],
            Defense: v[0]["Defense"],
            SpAttack: v[0]["Sp. Atk"],
            SpDefense: v[0]["Sp. Def"],
            Speed: v[0]["Speed"]}})
        .entries(data);
```

I was using this line of code to flatten it down when it was just a two level nest, but I'm not really sure how (if it's possible) to modify it to work for a three level one:

```
 var flatData = d3.values(d3.values(newData, function (d){return d.key})).map(function(e){return e.value});
```

And from there I would make the scales and the stack and the bars and so on. Is there any way to flatten this down to use, or am I going about this in the wrong direction? As I said, I'm pretty new with this. so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `d["Type 1"]` is not likely to return anything on the shared sample dataset, as there is no key called `Type 1`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. The dataset I put in the first code snippet is the result of the d3.nest() in the third code snipped. The dataset that pulls from is a csv file, with a column named "Type 1"